# pyinstaller causing weird issues

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use pyinstaller to create a standalone exe of a script that I wrote, which I have done in the past with the -F flag. This time around, I am having an issue.

The exe builds fine and can run, but when I run it with any cmdline arguments besides -h (help), the program just repeatedly prints "argument -f/--file is required" (which it is). This however happens even if I put -f 'filename', and normally the program is supposed to exit on this error, but it just hangs and repeatedly prints the error.

Has anyone seen a similar issue to this? The .py file runs completely as expected but as soon as I build it into an exe it starts exhibiting this weird behavior.

EDIT:

Okay, so I have done a little more research into this and now I am thinking the issue is even weirder... I have all my argparse stuff separated into its own function, as such:

```
def parseArgs():
''' Parse command line arguments '''
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="desc")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', required=True, dest='input_file', help='Text file containing the list of hosts')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--processors', required=False, dest='processors', help='Specify the number of processors to use. If omitted \
                        this will default to use as many processors as are available')  
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', required=False, action='store_true', help='Print additional output to the console', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-u', '--unc', required=False, dest='unc_path', help='UNC Path to copy results to. If omitted, results will need to be copied \
                        off later. Format UNC path as normal, with a trailing backslash, i.e. \\\\server\path\share\\', default='')

args = parser.parse_args()

# Check UNC path and fix issues with trailing slashes, etc.
if args.unc_path != '':
    args.unc_path = args.unc_path.replace('\\', '\\\\')

return args
```

This is obviously called in the main function. I have found that this portion of the program actually works fine. I have some STDOUT output at a point in the main function AFTER parseArgs() is called and I see that on the screen as normal.

What's very strange is that after another one of my (completely unrelated to parseArgs()) functions is called, then I am getting the output as if there is some error with the arguments that I gave (which there is not, keep in mind this works completely normally with the .py file, just not after packaging it as an exe).

If it makes any difference, the function that I am calling is used to copy files to a number of remote hosts (using XCOPY) using pool.map() to split the work among subprocesses.

Does anyone have any idea why I would be seeing output related to argparse well after that portion of my program has finished executing?

ANOTHER EDIT: It does seem like this has something to do with the multiprocessing because the argparse errors that come up sometimes overlap (as I said the same error telling me -f is required repeatedly prints to the screen).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you using? Also, can you add your code between `if __name__ == "__main__":` and your call to `main()`? I'm assuming you have that somewhere.